# ubuntu 12.04 stuck on splashscreen - not due to upgrade

Tags: plymouth

All of a sudden when I startup my comp I'm stuck at the splash screen and never get anywhere. I'm on 12.04 but the upgrade isn't the problem as I've been running it without any problems so far.

I changed the display settings as it was set to run on 2 screens and restarted and that's where I'm at now.

Does anyone have any idea on what's causing this? I mean surely not just from changing my display setting?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting .Xauthority, this worked for me.
Try to see the lightdm logs in /var/log/lightdm

Other things to try: 
A) reinstall lightdm (apt-get remove, and then install)
B) install gdm instead of lightdm. (lightdm and gdm are the "login screens")

Press ctr+alt+f1 to go to a console from X, and then Alt+F7 or Alt+f8 to go back to X.

Comment: Hi, with the ctr+alt+f1 I got to the console and I removed .Xauthority but to no avail. Then I removed the file Xorg.conf and I rebooted and now it works! Thanks very much!